# Does $\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\Aut(\Aut(\dots\Aut(G)\dots))$ stabilize?

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

Purely for fun, I was playing around with iteratively applying $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}\Aut$ to a group $G$; that is, studying groups of the form

$$ {\Aut}^n(G):= \Aut(\Aut(\dots\Aut(G)\dots)). $$

Some quick results:

- For finitely-generated abelian groups, it isn't hard to see that this sequence eventually arrives at trivial group.
- For $S_n$, $n\neq 2,6$, the group has no center and no outer automorphisms, and so the conjugation action provides an isomorphism $G\simeq \Aut(G)$.
- Furthermore, I *believe* that if $G$ is a non-abelian finite simple group, then $\Aut(\Aut(G))\simeq \Aut(G)$, though this is based on hearsay.
- If one considers topological automorphisms of topological groups, then $\Aut(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}$, and so $$\Aut(\Aut(\mathbb{R}))\simeq \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}.$$

When the sequence $\Aut^n(G)$ is constant for sufficiently large $n$, we will say the sequence **stabilizes**.  Despite my best efforts, I have been unable to find a group $G$ such that the sequence $\Aut^n(G)$ is provably non-stabilizing.  Is this possible?

A slightly deeper question is whether there are groups $G$ such that the sequence becomes periodic after some amount of time.  That is, $\Aut^n(G)\simeq \Aut^{n+p}(G)$ for some $p$ and for $n$ large enough, but $\Aut^n(G)\not\simeq \Aut^{n+m}(G)$ for $m$ between 0 and $p$.  A simple way to produce such an example would be to give two groups $G \not\simeq H$ such that $\Aut(G)\simeq H$ and $\Aut(H)\simeq G$.  Does anyone know an example of such a pair?

Comment: Funny - I was about to ask this question a week or so ago, but decided against it for some reason.

Comment: I don't think the sequence eventually stabilizes to 0 for all finitely generated abelian groups, e.g. Aut(Z/2 \times Z/2) = S_3.

Comment: This is a beautiful result: "if G is a non-abelian finite simple group, then Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G)." Does anyboday have a proof, hint of reference?

Comment: Proved in Burnside's book, second edition, I forget the page number.

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Here is a PhD thesis [Automorphism towers of general linear groups](http://search.proquest.com/docview/304622085?pq-origsite=gscholar)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I remember that my old grad classmate from Berkeley, Joel David Hamkins, worked on the transfinite version of this problem.  [The Automorphism Tower Problem](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/%7Esthomas/book.ps), by Simon Thomas, is an entire book on this subject.  The beginning of the book gives the example of the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$, in the sense of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ltimes \mathbb{Z}$.  It says that the automorphism tower of this group has height $\omega+1$.  It also treats Joel's theorem, which says that every automorphism tower does stabilize, transfinitely.  A [Proceedings paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2044505) with the same author and title says that Wielandt showed that every finite centerless group has a finite automorphism tower.

---

An improved answer:  Simon's book later shows that the automorphism tower of the finite group $D_8$ has height $\omega+1$, and that for general finite groups no one even knows a good transfinite bound.  (The $8$ may look like a typo for $\infty$, but it's not :-).) Apparently the centerless condition is essential in Wielandt's condition.

Also, to clarify what these references mean by the automorphism tower, they specifically use the direct limit of the conjugation homomorphisms $G \to \mbox{Aut}(G)$.  $D_8$ is abstractly isomorphic to its automorphism group.  This is a different version of the question that I suppose does not have a transfinite extension.  Section 5 of Thomas' book implies that it's an open problem whether the tower terminates in this weaker sense, for finite groups.

Finally an arXiv link to Joel Hamkins' charming paper, [Every group has a terminating transfinite automorphism tower](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808014).

---

As other people in this thread have pointed out, it's unsatisfying to make an automorphism tower that only stabilizes transfinitely as a direct limit, when all of the finite terms of the tower are abstractly isomorphic to the base group $G$.  I Googled around a bit more and came back to the same two sources, Thomas' book, and this time a joint result of Hamkins and Thomas which is in chapter 8 of the book.

If an automorphism tower stabilizes after exactly $n \in \mathbb{N}$ steps in the direct limit sense, then it also stabilizes after exactly $n$ steps in the weaker abstract isomorphism sense.  (Otherwise the direct limit "wouldn't know to stop".)  Hamkins and Thomas do better than that.  For any *two* ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which may or may not be finite numbers, they find *one* group $G$ whose automorphism tower has height $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in two different models of ZFC set theory.  (Whether it's really the "same" group in different worlds is unclear to me, but their models are built to argue that it is so.)  I would suppose that it is possible to make a tower without isomorphic terms by taking a product of these groups, even without the two-for-one property.

Other than [one paper on the Grigorchuk group](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.GR/0308127) by Bartholdi and Sidki, I haven't found anything on automorphism towers of finitely generated groups.  The Grigorchuk group has a countably infinite tower, but I'd have to learn more to know whether the terms are abstractly isomorphic.

Comment: Awesome!  Do you know if these transfinite bounds are effective enough to prohibit the existence of periodic towers?

Comment: At this point I can't do any more than you can, namely read these papers.  Just skimming at the book, it does discuss periodic automorphism towers, but I'm no longer sure where.

Comment: Minor typo: that last D\_8 should be a D\_\infty.

Comment: It may look like a typo, but it's not!


Comment: Its interesting that they use the conjugation action map in such a necessary way.  It means that in my above example with the real numbers, the direct limit at \omega is just the trivial group.  Therefore, in their sense, it doesn't stabilize until \omega, even though in my weaker sense, it stabilzes at 1.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, for mentioning my theorem so nicely! In the result I proved with Simon, it really is set-theoretically the same group whose tower varies in height, since we change the height by going to a forcing extension of the universe. All sets in the former universe still exist in the larger univese, including the desired group.

Comment: About periodic towers, the last few questions in Scott's old book Group Theory (1960s) ask about the possibility of periodic automorphism towers, but I believe that no examples are known with period 2 or larger. Also unkown is whether there is a finite group with an uncountable tower (in my sense).

Comment: When the initial group G is centerless, then all the groups in the tower are centerless, and so by identifying each group with its copy in the next, the tower is builiding up a larger and larger group. The direct limit corresponds to taking unions at limit stages, which is the most natural thing. When the groups are not centerless, my theorem is proved in part by arguing that eventually a centerless group appears in the tower.

Comment: Joel: Hi!  Changing universes is something that I will never understand well.  If you can change the automorphism group by enlarging the universe, then I am guessing that you can make two groups isomorphic that were not isomorphic before.  My naive question is whether it is shallow knowledge that two groups are the same, but in different universes.  I suppose it would help if your groups are completely explicit in ZF, but I only skimmed your work so I don't know if that is so.


Comment: The group whose tower changes is literally the same group, considered in one universe and then again in a larger universe, obtained by forcing. The method of forcing allows one sometimes to add new outer automorphisms of a group, and this is how we control the automorphism tower. The key step was to realize that we can have two rigid non-isomorphic objects (trees on omega_1), which can be made isomorphic in a forcing extension, while remaining rigid. For the full proof, we build complex assembleges of such trees, whose isomorphism relation can be tightly controlled by forcing.

Comment: Just as a more elementary answer to the question "can [elnarging the unierse by forcing] make two groups isomorphic that weren't isomorphic before?": many of the simplest forcings collapse cardinalities, i.e. make _sets_ isomorphic that weren't so before.  For instance, you can add a bijection $\omega \rightarrow \omega_1$ by using "injective finite partial functions" as forcing conditions. Then eg free abelian groups on these sets gives groups that become isomorphic.

Comment: Just to answer the question about abstract isomorphism within the tower of Grigorchuk's group: in that lucky case, the automorphism tower is an "inverse" to the lower central series; i.e. the $n$th l.c.s. subgroup of the $n$th automorphism group of $G$ is $G$ itself. So no terms are abstractly isomorphic: $\operatorname{Aut}^n(G)$ has the property that the groups $\gamma_i$ in its lower central series are finitely generated precisely for $i\ge n$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I'm sure it's a stupid question, but why is the automorphism group of a centreless group centreless?

Comment: @LSpice Not at all. It is an easy calculation to see that $\theta\circ i_g\circ\theta^{-1}=i_{\theta(g)}$, where $\theta$ is an automorphism of $G$ and $i_g$ means the inner automorphism of conjugation by $g$. This is how you can show that $\text{Inn}(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$. But it also shows that the centralizer of $\text{Inn}(G)$ in $\text{Aut}(G)$ is trivial, and so $\text{Aut}(G)$ is centerless if $G$ is.

Answer (score 46):

"if G is a non-abelian simple group, then Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G)."

This is Theorem 7.14 (Page 162) of

Rotman, Joseph J. (1995), An introduction to the theory of groups,
Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag, ISBN 978-0-387-94285-8
© 1995 Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.
ISBN 0-387-94285-8 Springer-Verlag New York Berlin Heidelberg
ISBN 3-540-94285-8 Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg New York

All the best,

Fernando.

Comment: Indeed, I have the extract in my answer.

Answer (score 31):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$I don't know about non-stabilizing, but rigidity provides many examples that stabilize quickly.

1) Let $\pi$; be the fundamental group of a finite volume hyperbolic manifold $M$ of dimension $\ge 3$ with no symmetries (that is, no nontrivial self-isometries). Negative curvature implies that $\pi$; is centerless, so the map $\pi\to \Aut(\pi)$ is injective. Mostow-Prasad rigidity says that $\operatorname{Out}(\pi) = \operatorname{Isom}(M)$, so the lack of isometries implies that $\operatorname{Out}(\pi)$ is trivial and $\Aut(\pi) = \pi$. [This works verbatim for lattices in higher-rank semi-simple Lie groups subject to appropriate conditions.]

2) Let $\pi=F_d$ be a free group of rank $2\le d\lt \infty$. Then $\Aut(F_n)$ is a much larger group; however, Dyer-Formanek showed that $\operatorname{Out}(\Aut(F_n))$ is trivial. Thus since $\Aut(F_n)$ is clearly centerless, we have $\Aut(\Aut(F_n)) = \Aut(F_n)$.

3) Interpolating between these two examples, if $\pi=\pi_1(S_g)$ is the fundamental group of a surface of genus $g\ge 2$, then $\Aut(\pi)$ is the so-called "punctured mapping class group" $\text{Mod}_{g,^*}$, which is much bigger than $\pi$. Ivanov proved that $\operatorname{Out}(\text{Mod}_{g,^*})$ is trivial, and since $\text{Mod}_{g,^*}$ is again centerless, we have $\Aut(\Aut(\pi_1(S_g))) = \Aut(\pi_1(S_g))$.

In each of these cases, rigidity in fact gives stronger statements: Let $H$ and $H'$ be finite index subgroups of $G = \Aut(F_n)$ or $\text{Mod}_{g,^*}$. (This class of groups can be widened enormously, these are just some examples.) Then any isomorphism from $H$ to $H'$ comes from conjugation by an element of $G$, by Farb-Handel and Ivanov respectively. In particular, $\Aut(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. Rigidity gives the same conclusion for $H = \pi_1(M)$ as in the first example and $G = \operatorname{Isom}(H^n)$ [which is roughly $\operatorname{SO}(n,1)$]. It seems that by carefully controlling the normalizers, you could use this to construct examples that stabilize only after $n$ steps, for arbitrary large $n$.

---

Edit: I find the examples of $D_8$ and $D_\infty$ unsatisfying because even though $\operatorname{Inn}(D)$ is a proper subgroup of $\Aut(D)$, we still have $\Aut(D)$ isomorphic to $D$. Here is a general recipe for building similarly liminal examples. Let $G$ be an infinite group with no $2$-torsion so that $\Aut(G) = G$ and $H^1(G;\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}) = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. (Edited: For example, by rigidity, any hyperbolic knot complement with no isometries has these properties; by Thurston, most knot complements are hyperbolic.) The condition on the $2$-torsion implies that for any automorphism $G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \to G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, the composition

$$G \to G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \to G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \to G$$

is an isomorphism. From this we see that $\Aut(G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}) / G = H^1(G;\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}) = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. By examination the extension is trivial, and thus $\Aut(G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}) = G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. However, the image $\operatorname{Inn}(G \times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ is the proper subgroup $G$.

Comments: looking back, this feels very close to your original example of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Interesting that it's (seemingly) much harder to find group-theoretic conditions to force the behavior the way you want, while topologically it's easy.

Also, if you instead take $G$ with $H^1(G;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ having larger dimension, say $H^1(G;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$, this blows up quickly. You get $\Aut(G \times \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z) = G \times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$, but then $\Aut(\Aut(G \times  \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z))$ is the semidirect product of $H^1(G;(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2) = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^4$ with $\Aut(G) \times \Aut((\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2) = G \times \operatorname{GL}(2,2)$. Already the next step seems very hard to figure out. However, if you had enough control over the finite quotients of $G$, perhaps you could show that the linear parts of these groups don't get "entangled" with the rest, so that the automorphism groups would act like a product of $G \times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^n$ with something else, with n going to infinity. If so, this could yield an example where the *isomorphism types* of the groups never stabilize.

Comment: Laurent Bartholdi and Said Sidki compute the automorphism tower of the Grigorchuk group, which is centerless.  In the direct limit sense, the tower has height omega+1.  But I can't quickly see whether the terms in the tower are abstractly isomorphic.

http://arxiv.org/abs/math.GR/0308127


Answer (score 16):

I had a group theory course with Suzuki in 1993, and he proved that

- if G is a non-abelian finite simple group, then Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G).

I don't have that proof any longer, so this is still just hearsay, but with pedigree!

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: In the finite case it's tempting to use Schreier's conjecture (which is a hard theorem), but it's true for arbitrary non-abelian simple $G$ (for which $G$ might embed into $\mathrm{Out}(G)$).

Answer (score 15):

For reference, note that the Wielandt Automorphism Tower Theorem states:

> Let *G* be a finite group, and assume that **Z**(*G*) = 1. Write *G*<sub>1</sub> = *G*, and for *i* > 1, *G*<sub>i</sub> = Aut(*G*<sub>i - 1</sub>). Then up to isomorphism, there are only finitely many different groups among the *G*<sub>i</sub>.

In fact, I quote the above result from Martin Isaacs' *Finite Group Theory*; more precisely, the result can be found on page 278 in Chapter 9 of this publication. Isaacs discusses this result in the context of subnormality in some depth and proves it as well.

Comment: Its an excellent result, but it doesn't rule out the possibility of a finite cycle which is stable.  

Comment: Greg, it does rule that out, since when the first group is centerless, you can prove inductively that all the groups are centerless, and so they must get larger unless you've reached a fixed point.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that $Aut(G)$ is complete for any simple (not necessarily finite) group. The proof of this is in Rotman's book, but it is [very short](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/rotmanaut.pdf).

Comment: I guess "the group $A$ is complete" means "the conjugation map $A \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is an isomorphism"?

Comment: Rotman's definition is "$G$ is complete if it is centerless and every automorphism of $G$ is inner."

Comment: @Bysshed, indeed, that is the same as saying that $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Since the link is broken, here is a proof. Let $A = \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Note $G$ is normal in $A$. If $N$ is another normal subgroup of $A$ then $N \cap G$ is normal in $G$, so either $N$ contains $G$ or $[N, G] \leq N \cap G = 1$, which means $N$ acts trivially on $G$, so $N = 1$. Hence $G$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$ ($G$ is "monolith" in $A$). Hence any automorphism $\alpha$ of $A$ preserves $G$, so agrees with some $\phi \in A$ on $G$. Now check that the action of $\alpha$ on $A$ is just conjugation by $\phi$.

Answer (score 13):

I proved with Denis Osin in arXiv:math/0605553 that if G is a (word) hyperbolic group with property (T), then Aut(G) contains Inn(G)=G as a subgroup of finite index. So Aut(G) is hyperbolic and has (T), and we can iterate to get an automorphism tower in which each group is hyperbolic and has (T). A question I like (even though this seems idle curiosity) is whether this automorphism tower always stabilizes. I have no clue how to approach it.

Comment: Hi Igor,
There is lots of cool stuff in your paper with Denis, but the theorem you claim is originally due to Paulin in MR1105339 in 1991.  He explicitly stated that if G is hyperbolic with Property (T) then Out(G) is finite as a corollary of his main theorem.  