# Criteria for Aut(G) to be simple

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is well known that the automorphisms of a group $G$ form a group under composition, and that the group of inner automorphisms $\phi (x)=gxg^{-1}$ forms a normal subgroup of $\mbox{Aut}(G)$. Thus, $\mbox{Aut}(G)$ is simple if and only if either $\mbox{Inn}(G)=\mbox{Aut}(G)$ or $\mbox{Inn}(G)$ is trivial. In the second case, since $G/Z(G)=\mbox{Inn}(G)$, $G$ must be abelian. My question is, when does $\mbox{Inn}(G)=\mbox{Aut}(G)$? Or, as it is unlikely that the general case is not fully understood, are there nice classes of groups for which there are a nice set of criteria for $\mbox{Inn}(G)=\mbox{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: There are some examples at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group .

Comment: One more remark: "if and only if" is wrong. $G=S_n$ for $n\neq 6$ is not simple, yet Inn = Aut.

Comment: Inn(G) = Aut(G) does not imply Aut(G) is simple.  For instance G nonabelian of order 6 is not simple, but Inn(G) = Aut(G).  If G is centerless, then Inn(G) = Aut(G) is called being a **complete group**.  If Aut(G) is simple, then Inn(G) = Aut(G) is simple, so G/Z(G) is simple.  Roughly speaking G is **quasi-simple** and G/Z(G) is simple and **complete**.  Modulo some A5 x 2 silliness, this is more or less a classification of G with Aut(G) simple.

Comment: @Jack: how do you know G/Z(G) is complete? 

Comment: @Steve: there are only a few cases where it could fail (it might), so I would just check the list.  I believe none of the cases work out, so it is complete.  I'll check more carefully tonight.

Comment: @Jack: OK, I thought you had derived it from the info in your comment.  But you're relying on the classification, right? Thanks for responding.

Comment: This question is perilously close to duplicate-hood: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36175/is-there-any-criteria-for-whether-the-automorphism-group-of-g-is-homomorphic-to-g .

Comment: @Steve: yes, using the classification to rule out non-cyclic multipliers.  Actually, as I start to make the list of all finite G it is getting fairly long, so I'll wait for some clarification from Daniel Miller before answering a question he may not have asked: For which finite groups is Aut(G) simple?  Rather than for which groups does Aut(G) = Inn(G), which I agree is pretty close to the question Henry Wilton linked.

Comment: @Steve D: In point of fact 2.Sz(8) has Sz(8) as its automorphism group, and Sz(8) has Sz(8):3 as its, so no G/Z(G) need not be complete.

Comment: This question would be even more interesting when combined with the result that Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G) when G is non-abelian simple.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an approximation of an answer to "For what finite groups is Aut(G) simple?"

As Daniel Miller mentioned, Inn(G) is a normal subgroup of Aut(G), so for Aut(G) to be simple either Inn(G) = 1, in which case G is abelian, or Inn(G) = Aut(G) is simple.  The former case should be somewhat easy to handle assuming G is finite.  In the latter case, we have that G/Z(G) is simple.  If G is also perfect, then G is called **quasi-simple**.  Of course, G need not be perfect as G ≅ A<sub>5</sub> × 2 shows.  However, I believe this is the only obstruction, so ignoring a possible cyclic direct factor of order 2, G/Z(G) is simple, and G is quasi-simple.  The finite quasi-simple groups and their automorphism groups are classified, but the classification is a bit long.  For a fixed simple group, X = G/Z(G), there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of quasi-simple groups D such that D/Z(D) = X.  In fact there is a unique largest one called the Schur cover, that I'll call D.  If Z(D) is cyclic, then in fact Aut(G) = Aut(X) = Aut(D) does not pay any attention to the center.  So all we need to do is find all X with Aut(X) = X [and each one works], and all X with Z(D) non-cyclic [and check which ones work].

Having done most, but not all, of that, I thought it might help to record the basic result:

If G = H×T where T=1 if H is abelian and T is cyclic of order dividing 2 otherwise, and where H is on the following list, then Aut(G) is simple:

- cyclic of order 3, 4, or 6
- elementary abelian of order 2<sup>n</sup> for n ≥ 3
- M11, 2.Sz(8), J1, 2.Sp(6,2), M23, M24, Ru, 2.Ru, Co3, Co2, Ly, Th, Fi23, Co1, 2.Co1, J4, B, 2.B, E7(2), M
- Ω(2n+1,2) for n ≥ 3
- Sp(2n,2) for n ≥ 3
- E8(p) for any prime p
- F4(p) for any prime p
- G2(p) for any prime p ≥ 5

Additionally if Aut(G) is simple, then G = H×T as above, except possibly H/Z(H) is on the following list:

- L3(4), U4(3), U6(2), 2E6(2)
- Ω<sup>+</sup>(4n,q) for certain q

These are groups with non-cyclic multiplier other than Sz(8) [definitely an example] and Ω<sup>+</sup>(8,2) [not an example].  The Ω<sup>+</sup>(4n,q) case should be mostly easy, as there are too many automorphisms to kill.  The others would be easy in an ideal world, but as far as I know our computational knowledge of these groups is limited and/or flawed.  Of course, I also need to check the abelian case carefully, but I think 3,4,6 and 2^n are the only abelian examples.

It would make another good answer: **For what torsion abelian groups G is Aut(G) simple?**  This would handle the abelian groups here, as well as some of the original poster's interest, without delving into the nastier aspects of abelian groups.

Comment: Torsion abelian groups split into p-components, so you're really asking about abelian p-groups (ignoring a C_2 factor).  But if the group has exponent higher than 2, inversion is a central automorphism.  So we really only care about elementary abelian 2-groups. In other words, you got all of them.

Comment: Thanks!  I had only been considering multiplication on one factor (a "diagonal" automorphism) and so missed the key property of **central** inversion.

Comment: $M_{24}$ is also a sporadic group with trivial outer automorphism group, so it needs to be added (without any covers, since it has trivial Schur multiplier) to your third family of groups.

Answer (score 4):

Obraztsov has shown that if $p$ is a sufficiently large prime, then there exists a finitely generated infinite simple complete group $G$, all of whose proper subgroups are cyclic of order $p$. In particular, $G$ is an example of a group such that $Aut(G)$ is an infinite simple group. The relevant reference is:

V. N. OBRAZTSOV,
`On infinite complete groups', 
Comm. Algebra 22 (1994) 5875--5887

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to your exact question (which I interpreted to be 'When does $\mathrm{Inn}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?'---as pointed out in the comments, this is not the same as asking for $\mathrm{Aut}G$ to be simple), and is only really interesting if you care about examples where $G$ is infinite.

If you do care about $G$ infinite, then a natural slight weakening is to ask for criteria for $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ to be finite.  One such criterion is provided by [Paulin's Theorem](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=260394&vfpref=html&r=35&mx-pid=1105339).

**Theorem.**  If $G$ is word-hyperbolic and $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ is infinite then $G$ splits (as an amalgamated free product or HNN extension) over a virtually cyclic subgroup.

It is [known](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3854) that, using some suitable definition of 'randomly chosen', a randomly chosen finitely presented group is torsion-free, word-hyperbolic and does not split.  So one can conclude that a 'randomly chosen' finitely presented group $G$ is of finite index in its automorphism group.

Comment: Just to clarify: in these examples, $G$ (and hence $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$), is never simple.

Answer (score -3):

let $G$ be non ableian group and $A$ be set of all groups including $Z(G)$. for All H in A,send H to Z(H)(Notice that this is a map from A to A). notice if Z(H)=Z(G) all H in A, it cause a contradiction(easy to show) if Inn(G)=Aut(G) then there is a uniqe proper group with Z(H)=Z(G)  in A.

M.Y.K

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading this and figuring out exactly what you are saying.  When you say "set of all groups", do you mean subgroups of $G$?  Also, you may want to use dollar signs (like in LaTeX) around your math phrases.  I've done it for your first sentence.

Comment: A={H<G|Z(G)<H} i.e A is the set of all subgroups of G including in Z(G). and first notice that Z(H)£A for all H in A. so, let f:A->A be function which send H to Z(H). first show that if f(H)=Z(G) for all H, it cause a contradiction since  center of G is properly contained  in a abelian subgroup of G if G is nonabelian. claim: if Inn(G)=Aut(G) then f(H)=Z(G) for only a uniqe element (G,Z(G) is trivially satisfy this,I mean except them )