# Two groups that are the automorphism groups of each other

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

Let $H,K$ be two non-isomorphic  groups such that $H\cong Aut(K)$ and $K\cong Aut(H)$.

Is there any example of such groups ?

**Note:** I had asked the question [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096939/two-groups-that-are-the-automorphism-groups-of-each-other?noredirect=1#comment2240137_1096939).

Comment: I think this question is answered in the comments to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-mathrmaut-mathrmaut-mathrmautg-stabilize

Comment: @HJRW: I could not find which comment ?

Comment: I couldn't find the answer there either, although it seems hard to believe that nobody has thought about this problem before, or indeed whether there are any known examples of longer finite cycles of automorphism groups.

Comment: If the initial group is finite and centerless then there are no finite cycles of length more than $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. I meant for the finite case with no centre.

Comment: Having said that, Joel David Hamkins does write in a comment 'I believe that no examples are known with period 2 or larger.'  But I think he may be talking about 'strong' isomorphism (ie insisting that the isomorphisms are the maps that send elements to inner automorphisms).

Answer (score 6):

Computer search in sage/gap didn't found any solutions for orders up to $120$.

It didn't assume the orders are equal.