# Status of the automorphism tower problem for finite groups

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, automorphism-groups

This is problem 11.123 in the [Kourovka notebook](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300):

> For a given group $G$, define the following sequence
> of groups: $A_1(G) = G$, $A_{i+1}(G) = \operatorname{Aut}(A_i(G))$. Does there exist a finite group $G$ for
> which this sequence contains infinitely many non-isomorphic groups? (M. Short)

I'm familiar with Wielandt's negative answer in the special case that $\mathbf{Z}(G)=1$. Have any other advances been made?

Comment: Maybe https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sthomas/tower.pdf is helpful.

Comment: Just to have it linked, although it's not an answer: [Does $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(\cdots\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cdots))$ stabilize?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-declaremathoperator-autaut-aut-aut-dots-autg-dots-stabilize).